# How to get a Distance Matrix with the computation being made offline on my server

Tags: php, c++, matrix, dictionary, openstreetmap

I am looking to get an approximation of the travel distance and time between several locations.

Ideally, I want to be able to send in the GPS coordinates of the locations, use the data of OpenStreetMap, and get as an output a distance matrix with the given locations, all of this would be done offline on my AWS server. (Using PHP or C++ would be good)

I am really new to using OpenStreetMap. I have just downloaded the ile-de-france.osm.pbf, which is the map for a region of France.

I have no clue where to start. I am not even sure if it is simple to do it. 
Can anyone point me in the right direction? And If OpenStreetMap is not the best solution for getting a distance matrix offline, then what is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OSRM has a distance matrix call, but it's currently limited to a certain quantity of locations.
I've built a script to make large distance matrices with a **local** OSRM server (it's really simple to compile on Ubuntu).
Here it is https://github.com/sabas/OSRMdistance
I've computed square matrices of more than 300 locations...

Comment: That's nice! However, I'm using AWS EC2 for my servers, and I had a lot of problems building and running OSRM (EC2 is based on redhad/centOS), and ended up giving up :( I might give it a shot for Routino now (If OSRM won't work)

Comment: On ec2 there's a dedicated tutorial for compiling, I tried on a server which I believe was based on the same infrastructure some time ago https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/wiki/Building-and-Running-OSRM-on-EC2

Comment: I'm glad that helped, if you have some improvements or you rewrite the thing in another way let me know... (it would be cool to see if there are smarter ways to improve the results, I did basically a brute force script) For example doing this in a multithreaded way.

Comment: Yeah definitely, I will look into it and contribute if I can :)

Comment: There's a call that we can make in order to get a distance table, that gives travel time in 10th of a second. Check https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/wiki/Server-api at the end of the page. An example is http://server:5000/table?loc=lat1,lon1&loc=lat2,lon2&loc=lat3,lon3&loc=lat4,lon4&...&latX,lonX

Comment: https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/issues/1077 For now only 100 destinations max as I told in the answer :-) When I find some time I'll recompile my OSRM and check how it performs...

Comment: Great! let me know when you have an update on this :)

Answer (score 5):

For calculating traveling distances you have to install a router, too. Choose one of the available [online routers](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/online_routers) (many of them can be installed locally and used offline, too) or [offline routers](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/offline_routers). Good choices are [OSRM](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSRM), [GraphHopper](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/GraphHopper) and [gosmore](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Gosmore).

Answer (score -1):

There are simple formula to calculate distance between 2 GPS coordinates. For example (you may need to pay attention to the units)

```
double t1 = sin(y1) * sin(y2);
double t2 = cos(y1) * cos(y2);
double t3 = cos(x1 - x2);
double t4 = t2 * t3;
double t5 = t1 + t4;
double rad_dist = atan(-t5/sqrt(-t5 * t5 +1)) + 2 * atan(1.0f);
double mile = rad_dist * 3437.74677 * 1.1508;
double meter = mile * 1609.3470878864446;
```

To find the walking/vehicle distance, you break the path into checkpoints by matching nearest "ways" in the database.

Comment: This formula calculates the distance between 2 points as if it is a straight line. I am not asking about that. I'm asking more about how to use the roads of OpenStreetMap between 2 locations in order to get correct time and distance measurements by doing offline computation on my server